# PouchDb find : why is my index not used?

Tags: pouchdb

I'm using PouchDb and the plugin PouchDb-find to query my local DB in an ionic web app. In almost every use case, I get the following warning when querying whereas I've created an index:

```
{
    "docs": {
        ...
    },
    "warning": "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time"
}
```

Starting from an example of the plugin documentation, I get this warning so I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Here is an example:

```js
var db = new PouchDB('test');

var docs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  docs.push({title: 'Lorem ipsum ' + i, _id: 'doc' + (i + 1)});
}

db.bulkDocs(docs)
  .then(
    function () {
      return db.createIndex({index: {fields: ['title']}});
    })
  .then(
    function () {
      // return db.find({selector: {title: {$eq: 0}}}); // No warning
      return db.find({selector: {title: {$ne: 0}}}); // Warning
    })
  .then(
    function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    })
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Why the index is used when using `$eq` and is not with `$ne` ?

Then, I have a more complex case with the following query (assuming `'a.deep.property'` always exists and is an Array) :

```js
db.find(
    {
        selector: {
            $not:{
                "a.deep.property": {$size:0}
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I've created an index with the field `'a.deep.property'`. The index is not used either. What index do I need to create ?

I also tried to create an index manually and to use `query()` in the previous case but this was slower than using PouchDb-find.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ne` currently does not use any index. You would have to use something like `$gt` or `$lt` instead. E.g. instead of `$ne: 0` you would do `{$gt: 0, $lt: 0}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using `{$gt: 0, $lt: 0}` is very clever. I suppose my second use case with `$not`, a deep property and `$size` doesn't use any index either right? By the way, I don't know which operators are using or not an index but i think it might be mentioned in the project readme to avoid this kind of questions. Waiting for your answer to my question in this comment to accept your initial answer.