# Can $in / $or queries use indexes?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant, couchdb-mango

I'm playing with Mango queries on a CouchDB 2.0 instance, through the fantastic [pouchdb-find](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find).

A few times I got the dreaded `no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time` warning even though I ***was*** using indexed fields.

Just now I got it when selecting `"type": {"$in": ["a", "b"]}` or the equivalent `"$or": [{"type": "a"}, {"type": "b"}]` , even though an index on `type` exists.

Googling ([cloudant query docs](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html), [pouchdb-find docs](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find#api), [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497985/pouchdb-find-why-is-my-index-not-used)) didn't help, and in the latter @nlawson says that some predicates (`$ne` in the aforementioned question, but maybe my `$in` / `$or` fall into the same basket?) *"currently do not use any index"*.

- If I'm indeed in the same boat, what does that mean? Is the impossibility to use indexes on queries using certain predicates a limitation of the *mango backend*, or a pouchdb one?
- Am I doing something wrong / is there an index workaround to avoid this?

  - More generally, is there documentation I could read to get a deeper grip on how indexes work and how to troubleshoot them?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the full call to find? Are you specifying a sort? This may be a pouchdb-find limitation. I'm not seeing this issue when testing directly on Cloudant. Could you change your query to something like this: `selector: { _id: {"$gt":0}, type: {"$in": ["a", "b"]} }`

Comment: @markwatsonatx that was the full query (no sorting, just a bare selector on `type`). And adding `_id: {"$gt":0}` did the trick oÔ.

1. Can you explain what's going on?
2. Feel free to convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also confused as to why you need to include _id in a query when i created an index on selector.

Comment: @EricShell I asked about this `_id` trick in [this couchdb-user mailing-list thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1cd9fa2d063ca0f476d703e4f36fe62d366f9a2fd8910954dcd4798e@%3Cuser.couchdb.apache.org%3E). Turns out: it's *not* a way to use an index, quite the contrary: it's only a way to explicitly *tell pouchdb-find I know I'll be running without index*, because my query won't fit into CouchDB's final map/reduce + composite key-based indexing, thus requiring fetching `allDocs` and doing in-memory filtering. I'll let this settle for a while, and will answer my question with a "no".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my question: no, `$in`/`or` queries cannot use indices. I asked the question in [this user@couchdb mailing list thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1cd9fa2d063ca0f476d703e4f36fe62d366f9a2fd8910954dcd4798e@%3Cuser.couchdb.apache.org%3E), where Garren Smith answered and pointed to [Understanding Mango View-Based Indexes vs. Search-Based Indexes](https://cloudant.com/blog/mango-json-vs-text-indexes/) and [A look under the covers of PouchDB-find](http://www.redcometlabs.com/blog/2015/12/1/a-look-under-the-covers-of-pouchdb-find). To quote Garren,

> The reason that adding `"_id": {"$gt": 0}` works is because
>   pouchdb-find/mango fetches all the docs using the `_all_docs` index and then
>   processes the `$in` operator in memory.
>
> If you have a large database this will hurt. But you can use a better value
>   than `0` to reduce the number of documents that need to be sorted in memory,
>   which is a good thing.

So, careful, `"_id": {"$gt": 0}`is by no means a way to use an index (that's the impression I got when @markwatsonatx suggested it), it's only a way to suppress pouchdb-find's warning, by telling it *"I know this won't fit a map/reduce, I'll be running in-memory operations on allDocs, and I'm aware of the perf. consequences"*. Also,

> The warning is just to help anyone new to using Mango that what they are
>   doing isn't the best way on a large database but will be fine on a small
>   database. It's a fine way to experiment but once you start noticing performance issues, creating an index is the way forward.

I'll complement with a little benchmark I made, comparing different approaches to fetch {10, 100, 1000, 10000} "cases" (using selectors on an indexed field) from a db containing [10000 cases, 100000 noise documents]

`|number of cases fetched|10    |100    |1000    |10000 |
|-----------------------|------|-------|--------|------|
|$in                    |2452ms|2539ms |2474ms  |5032ms|
|$in + $gt              |905ms |784ms  |1014ms  |3805ms|
|$in + $gt + $lt        |5ms   |13ms   |100ms   |3854ms|
|$or                    |2638ms|11763ms|101279ms|-     |`